# How to show $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{3} \binom{2n}{n}} = 4 \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{\arcsin^{2}(x)}{x} \ dx$?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{3} \binom{2n}{n}} = 4 \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{\arcsin^{2}(x)}{x} \ dx.$$
Someone please show that this equation is correct !?

Answer (score 4):

It is known that 
$$
\arcsin(x)^2=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(2x)^{2n}}{n^2\binom{2n}{n}}
$$
see [*Companion to Concrete Mathematics - Mathematical Techniques and Various Applications Z. A. Melzak*](http://bookfi.org/book/1099324) p. 108

Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{4\arcsin(x)^2}{x}
&=\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{2}{x}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(2x)^{2n}}{n^2\binom{2n}{n}}dx\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2^{2n+1}}{n^2\binom{2n}{n}} \int_{0}^{1/2}x^{2n-1}dx\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2^{2n+1}}{n^2\binom{2n}{n}} \frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2n}}{2n}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^3\binom{2n}{n}}
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $~\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(2x)^{2n}}{n^2\displaystyle{2n\choose n}}=2\arcsin^2x$.

Comment: Hintier: to derive the series representation above, express the arcsine function in terms of logarithm by $\arcsin{(x)}=\frac{1}{i}\ln{\left(iz+\sqrt{1-z^2}\right)}$.

Comment: It follows from the fact that $\arcsin x=\displaystyle\int_0^x\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$ by means of [Newton's binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) and [Cauchy's product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product).

Comment: Hrmm, that works too I suppose. :)